# Should I be concerned if a Diffie-Hellman key generation is near instant?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I'm a bit new to key exchange and security, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm setting up an OpenVPN server on my home router, and I did a dummy run just to see if I got it all up and running (dummy run being that I only created one client key pair first time round).

My question is this. When I went to do it a second time "for real", when I got to the part where I generate my DH key, it was generated near instantly. The first time I did it yesterday, it took at least a couple of minutes for my machine to generate it. I did it in the same environment and machine (a VM Linux), so I'm wondering why the difference was so much? Should I be concerned that the second DH key is less secure because it took a lot less time to generate? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I don't really have much idea of how cryptography works :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My supposition given this information would be that the entropy ("true" randomness (or as true as is available to the computer)) source that the key generator was using already had plenty of entropy, likely because it was running longer or hadn't been tapped out already.

If you are concerned, you could regenerate until it generates slowly, but I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: When it takes a while to generate a key, that could mean that the key is in fact *worse*, because it was created with the minimum amount of entropy still considered adequate. But that's hard to tell without seeing the implementation. But I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: Thank you both! Nice to get a little more understanding of what was going on. I will leave it as it is. Thanks again :)